# Select Directory for subprocess_checkoutput

Tags: python, python-3.x

Looking for a bit of help trying to select a specified directory to search for files A, B and C.
Currently I have it working for when the script is in the same directory but cannot figure out how to get it to work for a specified directory `C:\\test_files`.

This is what i currently have working:

```
import subprocess

Machine_ids = ["A","B","C"]

files = subprocess.check_output("dir", shell=True)

files = files.decode("utf-8")
files = files.split("\r\n")
files = files[7:-3]

for i in range(0,len(files)):
    file = files[i]
    file = file.split(" ")
    file = list(filter(None, file))
    for ID in Machine_ids:
        if (file[3].find(ID) !=-1 and len(file[3]) == 6):
            files[i] = file[3]
            break
        else: 
            files[i] = None

files = list(filter(None, files))       
print(files)
```

The directory I'm looking for has multiple other files and I wan to specifically print the files A, B and C and exclude D, E and F.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `os.listdir()` method allows for the specification of a file or directory path. Don't forget to `import` the `os module`. The example below prints out the file names in the path you specify.

```
import os

path = "/Users/yourUserName/Desktop"  # Put your file path here
file_list = os.listdir(path)  # Pass the path variable in the function

print(file_list)
```

To satisfy your needs of searching for files in paths A, B, and C, you can create multiple path variables and pass them into the `os.listdir()` method. For example:

```
pathA = "path for path A"
pathB = "path for path B"
pathC = "path for path C"
```

**EDIT:** Printing specified files in a certain path.
Store the names of the files you want to search for in a list (`specific_files`) and check if each one is in the list of files that comes from using `os.listdir()`.

```
import os

path = "/Users/yourUserName/Desktop/"

specific_files = ["fileA", "fileB", "fileC"]

file_list = os.listdir(path)

for file in specific_files:
    if file in file_list:
        print(path + file)
```

Output:

```
/Users/yourUserName/Desktop/fileA
/Users/yourUserName/Desktop/fileB
/Users/yourUserName/Desktop/fileC
```

Comment: Hi there, doing that it gives me all the files within the directory however I only want to specify files A, B and C rather than all. Is that possible?

Comment: Are files A, B, and C in the same directory?

Comment: Yes, A, B and C are in the same directory, however there are also files D,E and F but only wan to print A, B and C.